Series with odd numbers
Please help me implement the following formula:

My attempts:
U = 1;
w = 50;

Plot[(4 U)/Pi (\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(10\)]\ \(
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(i\ OddQ[i]\)] Sin[i\ OddQ[i]\ w\ t]\)\)), {t, 
  0, 1}]

and
n = 10;
R = Table[j + 1, {j, 0, n, 2}];
Plot[(4 U)/Pi (\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = R[\([1]\)]\), \(Lenght[R]\)]\ \(
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(i\ OddQ[i]\)] Sin[i\ OddQ[i]\ w\ t]\)\)), {t, 
  0, 1}]

Thanks everyone.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[t_] = 4 V/Pi Sum[Sin[k w t]/k, {k, 1, Infinity, 2}]

(* (2 I V (ArcTanh[E^(-I t w)] - ArcTanh[E^(I t w)]))/π *)

V = 1;
w = 50;

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> All, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]]


EDIT: To avoid the presence of the complex constant
f2[t_] = f[t] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify

(* 1/π(-ArcTan[1 + Cos[50 t], -Sin[50 t]] + 
  ArcTan[1 + Cos[50 t], Sin[50 t]] - ArcTan[2 Sin[25 t]^2, -Sin[50 t]] + 
  ArcTan[2 Sin[25 t]^2, Sin[50 t]]) *)


Another way:
$Version

(*"14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"*)

Using:
Table[2 k - 1, {k, 1, 10}]
(* {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19} *)

.
Clear["Global`*"]

g[t_] = 4 V/Pi Sum[Sin[k w t]/k /. k -> 2 k - 1, {k, 1, Infinity}]

(*(2 I V (ArcTanh[E^(-I t w)]-ArcTanh[E^(I t w)]))/\[Pi]*)

V = 1;
w = 50;

Plot[g[t], {t, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> All, ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]]


You should refer to the documentation of Sum and OddQ. The former allows to set the magnitude of increments (using 2 gives odd numbers, of course), whereas the latter returns a truth value instead of 0 and 1, which I guess you had in mind.
With[
 {
  bigV = 1,
  \[Omega] = 50
  },
 Plot[
  (4 bigV)/Pi Sum[Sin[k \[Omega] t]/k, {k, 1, 10, 2}], 
  {t, 0, 1}]
 ]

Notice also that even if OddQ would return 0 and 1, which can be achieved by wrapping it in Boole, you would be dividing by 0 in your original attempt.
